# Why is the government of India probing Dr Zakir Naik for connection with terrorism after 26 years?

Tags: india, terrorism

According to Dr Zakir Naik's [biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakir_Naik#Biography), he started his preaching and founded IRF in 1991.

Even though numerous terrorist incidents took place [in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terrorist_incidents_in_India) and [Bangladesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Terrorist_incidents_in_Bangladesh_by_year) during the last 26 years, nothing happened during all these years. I.e. even though he was [regularly criticized](https://wikiislam.net/wiki/Zakir_Naik:_His_Background,_Views_and_Debates), no one ever linked him with terrorism.

What happened suddenly?

Why has Indian government started a probe against him [after 26 years](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/nia-approaches-interpol-for-red-corner-notice-against-zakir-naik/articleshow/58631670.cms) even though he was doing his job as he was doing 26 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the current right wing government wants to stop conversions. Since no substantial evidence could be gathered linking him to terrorist organisations the govt made up a case of foreign donations against him. Such articles with low factual content regularly hit the headlines in indian media outlets.

An example:

> http://www.financialexpress.com/india-news/zakir-naiks-irf-received-rs-60-crore-aid-for-religious-conversions-reports/688642/

1. This article names "many" joined ISIS but doesn't give out any specific names or numbers
2. Says "60 crores were used for conversion" - neither receiving donations nor propagating ones religion is a crime in India

Comment: Can you further prove the "low factual content" point

Comment: @SleepingGod see the example in my reply