# Why does Hindu nationalism actually work in India?

Tags: india

The ruling and seemingly most popular party in India right now is BJP. The premise of BJP is that of Hindu nationalism but I don't understand how such a thing as Hindu nationalism can ever replace the pre-existing Nehruvian secularism.

The reason I say that is, the idea of Hindu as a person with a set of X practices is illdefined. There are actually various sects and castes of Hinduism and in each they have different gods and different practices. These go as far as marital law, food choices etc.

Provisions to remedy the differences which arise to this and also historical mistreatment of certain caste already exist as Caste reservation, non uniform civil code etc. So, what more is BJP offering than what there is already?

Comment: A large part of BJP-style Hindu nationalism seems to be hatred of non-Hindus (especially Muslims). Have you read the relevant Wikipedia articles or done any other research?

Comment: Do you have reason to think I didn't ? @StuartF

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal opinion.

It is a very common perception in India that Muslims are invaders who sucked India dry for centuries.

For example,

- [The Mind of a Hindu Nationalist](https://youtu.be/vrxW7n73C7s)
- [How Mahmud Ghaznavi used religion for his interests?](https://youtu.be/VsK5Nb4JrbQ)
- [Were Turko-Mughals "Nation Builders"?](https://youtu.be/tZbgDWkT1xY)

This perception is taught in Indian textbooks and is also in vogue with the general Hindu population, even among so-called seculars.

Secular Hindus in India do not like to talk about these topics in public, thinking that they would fuel communal and religious tensions. However, they themselves also believe in this kind of stuff. In my other answer, I already wrote that the secular stream of politics in India has a clear and documented history of anti-Muslim perception and activities.

- [Why is Hindu nationalism such a powerful political force in India?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75452/32479)

Therefore, for BJP, the stage was always prepared. They only went one step further. I.e., they started talking about these perceptions in public and thereby appealed to the innermost feelings of general Hindus. Nowadays, they are cultivating these ideas in people's minds and thereby feeding on their dormant desires. In this way, they are exploiting people's sentiments in a very efficient and planned manner.