# Why did India vote in favor, on the July 12th UNHRC resolution condemning religious hatred and bigotry?

Tags: india, united-nations, human-rights

- [UN motion after Sweden Quran burning: How did your country vote?](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/7/12/un-bodys-motion-on-quran-burning-how-did-your-country-vote)

> The motion called for countries to review their laws and plug gaps
> that may “*impede the prevention and prosecution of acts and advocacy
> of religious hatred.*”
>
> Here is how countries voted:
>
> No:
>
> 1. Belgium;
> 2. Costa Rica;
> 3. Czech Republic;
> 4. Finland;
> 5. France;
> 6. Germany;
> 7. Lithuania;
> 8. Luxembourg;
> 9. Montenegro;
> 10. Romania;
> 11. UK;
> 12. US
>
> Abstained:
>
> 1. Benin;
> 2. Chile;
> 3. Georgia;
> 4. Honduras;
> 5. Mexico;
> 6. Nepal;
> 7. Paraguay
>
> Yes:
>
> 1. Algeria;
> 2. Argentina;
> 3. Bangladesh;
> 4. Bolivia;
> 5. Cameroon;
> 6. China;
> 7. Cuba;
> 8. Eritrea;
> 9. Gabon;
> 10. Gambia;
> 11. India;
> 12. Ivory Coast;
> 13. Kazakhstan;
> 14. Kyrgyzstan;
> 15. Malawi;
> 16. Malaysia;
> 17. Maldives;
> 18. Morocco;
> 19. Pakistan;
> 20. Qatar;
> 21. Senegal;
> 22. Somalia;
> 23. South Africa;
> 24. Sudan;
> 25. Ukraine;
> 26. UAE;
> 27. Uzbekistan;
> 28. Vietnam;

Why did India vote in favor when the last time they protested the introduction of [Islamophobia day at UNGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Day_To_Combat_Islamophobia) and also there is allegedly a [Hindutva government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75452/32479) in power who are [staunch Muslim-haters](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2023/05/11/modi-india-muslims-hatred-incitement/)?

Comment: I added a "need detailed answer" post notice to this question because it's the kind of question that attracts speculative answers, which then receive a ton of upvotes from new users who don't understand that we don't allow speculation. **If you want to answer, then source your answer from an official statement from the Indian UN delegation explaining their reasoning for the vote**. Do not bother writing answers based on conjecture and indirect evidence what their motivation *might* have been,

Answer (score 3):

We can only go by the explanation provided by the Indian representative to the UNHRC - that is that India's Constitution recognises the freedom of religion and that the country wants the international community to work together to eliminate intolerance, prejudice, and violence against religious followers.

His full remarks are below, and a digital recording of the proceedings may be found [here](https://conf.unog.ch/digitalrecordings/index.html?guid=public/12.0870/6106CF17-C7E8-4ECC-95FD-BC5E6C9785B6_15h01&position=4372&channel=ENGLISH).

> India rejects firmly and unequivocally all forms of religious
> intolerance and all acts of religious hatred, discrimination and
> violence. India is a multi-lingual, multi-religion and multi-cultural
> nation. Unity in diversity has been our civilizational motto. We in
> India celebrate our diversity, as reflected in our abiding respect for
> all religions and cultures. The Constitution of India guarantees to
> all citizens as a fundamental right, the freedom of conscience and the
> freedom to profess, practice and promulgate religion. It guarantees
> equal respect for all religions and peaceful coexistence of all
> religions. It has been on of the foundational tenets of India's
> secular polity and society. Inspired by the philosophy of the religion
> of humanity, India has always been committed to human rights.
>
> It is regrettable that there has been an increase in the prevalence of
> phobias against followers of various religions. In various regions of
> the world, we have witnessed defacement and destruction of temples and
> idols, glorification of desecration of idols, violation of Gurdwara
> premises, the massacre of sick pilgrims and numerous other acts of
> religious intolerance. There is a need for the international community
> to recognize the instances of intolerance, prejudice, phobia, and
> violence against followers of all religions and work together to
> eliminate them.
>
> Mr. President, the world is one family. It provides the basis for
> elimination of all kinds of religious hatred, discrimination and
> intolerance directed against followers of all religions. It is high
> time that Member States join hands to build a culture of equal respect
> for all religions and their peaceful coexistence.